# Why the output getting differed in hexadecimal integer to character conversion?

Tags: java

Why the output varies in both of the following codes since i am applying the same explicit type conversion.

```
    int hex = (char)0xA;
    System.out.println(hex);

    int hex = 0xA;
    System.out.println((char)hex);
```

Comment: After the first line, both programs are the same. But in the second line, the casting makes the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mortalus answered, the reason for the difference was because in one case you passed an int to println, in another case you passed a char.

I just wanted to add that I can see that in the first case you were attempting to create a char rather than an int however the syntax was incorrect.  Instead of:

```
int hex = (char)0xA;
```

use

```
char hex = 0xA;
```

In the first statement above, the literal 0xA is an int literal of decimal value 10.  You then explicitly cast to a char of value 10.  Finally you assign the char to an int variable hex.  Since 10 is valid for both int and char, an implicit conversion is performed, the char is converted back to an int, and you end up with an int variable, not a char variable.

In the second statement above we have the same literal value and assign it to a char.  An implicit conversion is performed and you have a char variable hex with a value of 10.

If you make the corresponding change to your examples, you will see that they now both print out the same result.

```
char hex = 0xA;
System.out.println(hex);

int hex = 0xA;
System.out.println((char)hex);
```

[update]

In each case this prints out the character whose value is 10 - which is interpreted by virtually every systems as a line-feed, followed by the system defined line separator sequence (since println guarantees that it will add a line separator to the output).

Note that on Windows, lines are typically separated by CR LF  (13 followed by 10) while on Linux/Mac systems lines are usually separated by LF (10).

So, on Windows, both statements will result in 3 bytes (10, 13, 10).  On Linux/Mac both statements will result in two bytes (10, 10).

Either way, the output will look like a couple of blank lines.  It will look fine on Linux/Mac - but might look odd on Windows because you are sending an invalid line separator.

BTW - I don't actually recommend the code above for generating line feeds.  Instead you should use the system property line.separator and use that string instead.

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator").toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.. Well Could you tell me what is the output printed while running thi

     System.out.println((char)hex);

Answer (score 2):

At the first line you send an `int` value to the `println` function.
At the second you send  `char` value hence the difference ..

Consider the following overloads for [System.out.println(char x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28char%29)
and an overload for : [System.out.println(int x)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28int%29)